# The format of if-else in the function is wrong

Tags: algorithm2e, ifthenelse

When using latex to write pseudo-code, using loops in the function, the vertical line position is wrong.

```
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}  
\usepackage{algpseudocode}  
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm} [t]
    
    \begin{algorithmic}
            
    \Function{victim\_func1}{a}
    
    \eIf{sec[i]}{
         A
    }{
         B
    }
    \EndFunction
    
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}  
\end{document}
```

The result displayed is：
[image]

The vertical line on the left should belong to if-else, but the position is wrong. How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: It seems that you use a mixture of algorithm packages. Hard to tell since you don't provide the full code.

Comment: I used a template, and I added what I thought was relevant. Don't know if it is enough?

Comment: Now it's better. You don't have to load `algorithmicx` since it is loaded automatically by `algpseudocode`. The problem is that you can't have both, `algorithm2e` and `algorithmicx`/`algpseudocode`, since they interfere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I commented the algorithmmicx package, the problem of if-else format still appeared.

Comment: There is no \function command in the algorithm package. If I don't use algpseudocode, how can I write a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`algorithm2e` provides a `function` environment. You can set the name of the function with `\caption` (no underscores allowed!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
  \begin{function}\caption{VictimFunc1(a)}
    \eIf{sec[i]}{
       A
    }{
       B
    }
  \end{function}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I want to write two functions, how can I put them together?

Comment: It would be best, if you'd ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I asked another question again. Would you mind looking at it for me?     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577048/how-to-organize-two-functions-together-for-display